# acknowledging someone one cannot put a name on

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

It is a way of ____________

- ... acknowledging someone one cannot remember the name right away
- ... acknowledging someone one cannot remember the name easily

Better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need a relative pronoun,

> "...someone, **whose** name one cannot remember right away."